# How to exclude username from gitlab url

Tags: git, gitlab

I just finished installing gitlab and noticed that when i create a new repo, the url to the repo includes my username right before the gitlab url.

```
git clone http://jonesdem@gitlab.example.com/jonesdem/firstrepo.git
cd firstrepo
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin master
```

I would like the url to look like so

```
git clone http://gitlab.example.com/jonesdem/firstrepo.git
cd firstrepo
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin master
```

Any idea which configuration setting i need to tweak to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a configurable option in GitLab, as it is commonly accepted practice to use URLs in the format GitLab is providing them

---

However, the following should work to the best of my knowledge:

In the directory of your git repository:

```
git clone http://gitlab.example.com/jonesdem/firstrepo.git
```

Then when you need to push:

```
git config credential.helper store
git push http://gitlab.example.com/jonesdem/firstrepo.git

Username for 'https://gitlab.example.com.com': <USERNAME>
Password for 'https://USERNAME@gitlab.example.com': <PASSWORD>
```

---

The `username` before the `@` on the HTTP(S) URL is used to indicate the user to authenticate as, you cannot push to a remote git repository if you have not authenticated - this is why it is present. It is common practice to use URLs such as `http://jonesdem@gitlab.example.com/jonesdem/firstrepo.git`, as opposed to using the method i have indicated above.